# Meaning of infinite eigenvalues in generalized eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

For a numerical problem I need the generalized eigendecomposition

$$\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{B P D P}^{-1}.$$

In some cases however, the matrix $\boldsymbol{B}$ becomes singular and I get infinite  eigenvalues. As far as I understand, the generalized eigendecomposition should also work for singular matrices. Else I could just use the regular decomposition of the equivalent problem

$$\boldsymbol{B}^{-1}\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{P D P}^{-1}.$$

In my case $\boldsymbol{B}$ is a hermitian matrix and typically real, and $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a complex symmetric matrix.
To be precise, consider the example:

$$\boldsymbol{B} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\quad \boldsymbol{A} = \begin{pmatrix} 1+i & 2i \\ 2i & 1+ i \end{pmatrix}.
$$

`scipy` gives me

```
from scipy import linalg

a = np.array([[1+1j, 2j], [2j, 1+1j]])
b = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]])
linalg.eig(a, b)
# (array([0.5+1.5j, inf+0.j ]),
# array([[-0.70710678-5.55111512e-17j, -0.70710678-5.55111512e-17j],
#        [-0.70710678+5.55111512e-17j,  0.70710678+5.55111512e-17j]]))
```

My algorithm fails due to the infinite eigenvalue `inf+0.j`, so I hope to understand the meaning of this infinite eigenvalues to hopefully find a solution to work around it.

---

edit: the problem to solve

The actual problem I need to solve is of the form

$$ \boldsymbol{C}(v) = \left[\int dx \int dy \int dz (\boldsymbol{A}(v) - \boldsymbol{B}f(x,y,z))^{-1}\right]^{-1} $$

If it is possible to calculate the generalized eigendecomposition, this problem can be solved

$$\boldsymbol{C}(v) = \boldsymbol{BP}(v)\boldsymbol{I}(v) \boldsymbol{P}(v $$

with the digonal matrix

$$ I_{ij}(v) 
= \delta_{ij} \frac{1}{\int dx \int dy \int dz \frac{1}{D_{ii}(v)-f(x,y,z)}}$$

with a known solution for the elements $I_{ii}(v)$. A brute foce solution is not possible, it would require $\sim 10^{12}$ matrix inversions.

Comment: Maybe it would help to use some pseudoinverse instead of real inverse.

Comment: This example is not possible. $\bf B$ removes information in directions which disqualify $\bf A$ from being what you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have no background in linear algebra. If I get you correctly, you are telling me that the product $\boldsymbol{BM}$ with a matrix $\boldsymbol{M}$ has always linear dependent rows and therefor cannot be a symmetric matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Symmetric matrices of all ranks exist including $1$ so it's not the symmetricity that is ruined.

If you do a regular eigenvalue decomposition on $\bf A$ you will find it has $2$ non-zero eigenvalues.

$\bf B$ only has $1$ non-zero eigenvalue. $\bf B$ being multiplied to the left will always remove one dimension with it's $0$ eigenvalue of whatever matrix is to the right of it. So even if ${\bf PDP}^{-1}$ is full rank, the multiplication with $\bf B$ will remove one dimension, making it unfittable to $\bf A$.

Comment: This helps a lot. There is, however, no apparent solution. I tried considering the QR decomposition $\boldsymbol{B}=\boldsymbol{QR}$ and use the eigendecomposition $\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{QPDP}^{-1}\boldsymbol{R}$. But this will suffer the same problem, as the second row of $\boldsymbol{R}$ is zero. I probably have to just interpolate the result.

Comment: @DerWeh : I don't understand what you are even trying to do, so it is not so easy to help further.

Comment: I wasn't expecting much further help. I just try to understand what are possible directions and what not. The actual problem is quite involved. I tried to add the minimal necessary context to the question, why I want the generalized eigendecomposition.